# If I change schema.xml then reIndex is neccessary in Solr or not?

Tags: string, solr, types, indexing

I **indexed** **2GB** of data. Now I want to **change** the **type** of **field** from **textSpell** to **string** type into **schema.xml**

**Current Schema :**

```
<field name="gram" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

**Required Schema :**

```
<field name="gram" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

So, I need to **reindex** the **whole data** or there is any other way to **reuse** the **same indexed data** without losing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to re-index the data. In some rare cases, you can get away without it. Since you're changing the field type, a re-index is highly recommended because the documents will need to be reanalyzed with their new field types in Solr.

Comment: You are sure about reindexing because reindexing is very expensive for me.

Comment: Yes, changing field types will change the way that data in that field will be transformed or normalized at index time because of the way each type is configured. If you don't reindex, your data won't undergo the transformations while any new data added to the index will cause inconsistency. Since you need to make a change, I'm assuming your textSpell type is different from the string type, so a reindex should be performed.

Have a look at the analyzers page for a better [understanding](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers,+Tokenizers,+and+Filters)

Comment: Is it the same with Elastic Search? I mean, for this kind of change does ES also require re-indexing?